# What is the function of the "loginName = "Friend"" below?

Tags: android

The loginName here is input for username. I assume that the "loginName = "Friend" will display "Friend" as default username if there is no input, but it's not right. So what is the meaning of that code and if I want to display "Friend" as default, How can I do?

```
package com.example.rubit.interactivestory.ui;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.rubit.interactivestory.R;

public class Story extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_story);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String loginName = intent.getStringExtra(getString(R.string.login_name));

        if (loginName == null) {
            loginName = "Friend";
        }
        Toast.makeText(this,loginName,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the default for when the input is null. But you probably have the issue that it's not null but empty (""). You should also check for:

```
if (TextUtils.isEmpty(loginName)) {
        loginName = "Friend";
}
```

Comment: Thank you I got it. Btw, is there any way that the input can be null in this case?

Comment: Yes, if you dont't add a String with the key "getString(R.string.login_name)" to your intent bundle.

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String loginName = intent.getExtras().getString(getString(R.string.login_name), "Friend");
```

By doing this, if your intentStringExtra is null, it will provide you the default **Friend** value. But for this minimumSDK required is 12.

Comment: Thanks. This works for the case loginName is null, but not work for the case input is "". So I think the above answer is quite better.

Comment: yes this works only when your value of key doesn't exists, means null